# Not able to start spark-shell as it yields error over hadoop cluster steup, however, works fine without hadoop cluster

Tags: scala, shell, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I remove the hadoop cluster set up folder then my spark-shell works perfectly fine, however, if I tried with hadoop cluster set up folder then spark-shell yields various errors like  "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState' in spark" even I didn't configure hive anywhere. Note that, even I tried by shut down the all cluster of hadoop and spark, but even spark-shell yields following error:

[image: Error during excecution of ./bin/spark-shell]

[image: second part of the same error]

Comment: When I tried to run the spark-shell  using root access then spark-shell works fine. When I try with current user then getting above mentioned error however I have given full access to the current user. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

run : mkdir /user/$whoami/spark-warehouse

then run : spark-shell --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=file:///user/$whoami/spark-warehouse

Comment: Can we avoid this hive installation as it is not required? If yes then plz let me know how?

Comment: Have your started the hadoop cluster before running spark-shell?

Comment: I tried both way i.e. with start and without start but no luck.... even I just now installed hive but still  getting the same error.

Comment: try this : 

spark-shell --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=file:///C:/tmp/spark-warehouse

Comment: try this : 
mkdir ~/spark-warehouse
spark-shell --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=file:///~/spark-warehouse

Comment: try this : mkdir /user/$whoami/spark-warehouse spark-shell --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=file:///user/$whoami/spark-warehouse

Comment: This command is not working proper as it gives error mkdir: unrecognized option '--conf'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140183/discussion-between-snchit-grover-and-chandan-gautam).

Comment: @sanchit ... that answer didn't work for me.. thats why I didn't accept the answer... I am still looking for an answer....